# Multiple request with AFNetworking

Tags: iphone, objective-c, afnetworking

I'm trying to do multiple request in background to download many jsons and check data from them but I don't know how to use AFNetworking in that case.

I tried to do like Wiki explaings but when it's going to download the second file then the app breaks. I want to do all the process in background.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

AFNetworking will definitely handle this. We use it for exchanging data with a RESTful set of services. The things to keep in mind:

- An operation (eg. AFHTTPRequestOperation) can only be used once.
- An operation is asynchronous.
- Put your operations in an NSOperationQueue, or use AFHTTPClient (suggested) to manage the operations for you.
- When sending multiple requests, always assume that the responses will come back in a random sequence. There is no guarantee that you will get the responses in the same sequence as the requests.

Hope this helps to point you towards a solution to your problem. Without more detail in your question, it's difficult to give you a specific answer.

Answer (score 6):

Check out `AFHTTPClient`'s 
[`enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperations:progressBlock:completionBlock:`](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/1.3.2/Classes/AFHTTPClient.html#//api/name/enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperations%3aprogressBlock%3acompletionBlock%3a), which lets you enqueue multiple requests operations at once with the added bonus of having a completion handler that is called when *all* of those requests have finished, as well as a block for tracking the progress. Also note, that every single operation can still have its own completion handler (useful if you have to process the results of a request, for example).

If you don't need to customize the request operation (and don't need individual completion blocks), you can also use [`enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperationsWithRequests:progressBlock:completionBlock:`](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/1.3.2/Classes/AFHTTPClient.html#//api/name/enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperationsWithRequests%3aprogressBlock%3acompletionBlock%3a), which allows you to pass an array of `NSURLRequest` directly without having to build the operations yourself.